# File not writing unless I set a trace and wait

Tags: python, excel, file, xlsxwriter, file-writing

I'm having a bizarre issue trying to write an `xlsx` file in Python. 
I'm using Python 2.7.x and `xlsxwriter` to write `xlsx` files.
Here's a code snippet for context:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('worksheet_name')
worksheet.write_row('A1', make_header_row)  // <---- ROW 1
... // initialize "fields" array
worksheet.write_row('A2', fields)           // <---- ROW 2
```

So here's the problem: **Row 1** gets written, no problem. **Row 2** never gets written... *unless* I stick a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` right above the line where I write Row 2. Waiting ~5 seconds in the `pdb` and then hitting `continue` will result in a *successfully written second row*.

I've tried `flush`ing the workbook right after `write_row`, making sure the file is `close`d... nothing works.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: That is indeed bizarre. I think you will need to include more information, such as the code you are using to initialize `fields`. See [how to create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).